# Making a project open source on behalf of my organization

Tags: open-source

I am working on a tool which has been developed  for the use in my organization. Recently the management decided to make this open source. This will be the first open source contribution from my company and by me .

How can I make a project open source which will also show that this is from this organization?
Is just naming it as orgName_toolName sufficient or is there any other practice that is followed?

I am planning to make this available in Github.

Comment: have the copyright notice mention the organization as author, either way consult the legal division for this

Comment: Word to the wise:  asking for legal information related to programming is perfectly fine, but we're also not lawyers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To release a project under an open-source license, you should take these steps:

1. Select an open source license that has acceptable terms for your organisation. You can find a list of open source licenses at http://opensource.org/licenses
2. Make sure that each file of the project has the appropriate copyright notice for the license you selected and that your organisation is indicated as the copyright holder.
3. Add any additional copyright related files, as required by the selected license, to your project
4. Publish the project on the internet, using a service of your choice. Github is a good one.